# custom page except front and index

Tags: layout

I want to format my document so as to fit its contents as I would like, but not keep this format for the front page and the index; as I need large margins for notes & equations but this particular layout make the cover and index look very weird, everything being put on the side.

I use this code to custom its format:

```
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0cm} 
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0cm}    
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{5cm}    
\setlength{\textwidth}{13cm}
\setlength{\textheight}{23cm}
```

and want to know if it is possible to either:

- reset it locally while being true on global
- set it on locally while being off on global

If this problem has no solution in LaTeX, I will simply save two documents, one unformatted and one formated and use pdf to merge the front page and index of the unformatted and the content of the formated.

Comment: Please provide an MWE (from `\documentclass...` to `\end{document`) that we can compile to see the structure of your document and what you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the layout settings locally through the `\geometry` command provided by the `geometry` package. In the example below I just change the margins:

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{geometry}
  \geometry{margin=3cm}

\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
\textbf{Titlepage}\\
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{titlepage} 
    
\tableofcontents

\newgeometry{margin=0.5cm}

\chapter{Small margins\index{Small Margins}}\lipsum

\restoregeometry

\chapter{Default margins\index{Default Margins}}\lipsum

\newgeometry{margin=6cm}

\chapter{Large margins\index{Large Margins}}\lipsum

\restoregeometry    

\printindex 
    
\end{document}
```